# How to output both a minified and non-minified version with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I got this error when trying to get two output in a single task

I want an `index.js` in `dist/`, and `index.min.js` in the same folder.

```
gulp.task('clean', (cb) =>
  del('dist/', cb)
);

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], () =>
  gulp.src('src/**.js')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe($.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
    .pipe($.rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'scripts'}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
);
```

This is the error:

```
[19:48:55] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[19:49:00] Using gulpfile ~/projects/ar-string/gulpfile.babel.js
[19:49:00] Starting 'clean'...
[19:49:00] Finished 'clean' after 19 ms
[19:49:00] Starting 'scripts'...

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1508:18)
at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:1516:11)
at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2008:9)
at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2016:9)
at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2022:9)
at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2042:43)
at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2222:73)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2095:19)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2055:24)
at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (/home/mohamed/projects/ar-string/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:24:4), <anonymous>:2335:20)
```

Note: i think the error is in babel

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951497/how-to-save-a-stream-into-multiple-destinations-with-gulp-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was in .babelrc file

before:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "only": "gulpfile.babel.js",
  "retainLines": true
}
```

After:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "retainLines": true
}
```